What "On your approach" means in this context?
I've playing a game called gta san andreas and I've ran into this phrase

Hey carl


you gotta stay nice and low on your approach or you pop up on the
radar

And two questions crossed my mind that is:
Nice → the word nice used here seems strange because i've learned the word "nice" means something cool, etc. But in this phrase I suposse it means "sable" so the character is basicaly saying

you gotta stay nice and low on your approach == you gotta stay
stable(the plane stable) and low on your approach

please correct if I'm wrong
and the main question is the idiom "On Someone's Approach" because I can't find this idiom anywhere, is this idiom a dialect of a specific group or something?
link of a video with context:
https://youtu.be/xf1dprm-QS0

It's not an idiom. Look in the dictionary for "approach" and you'll find a definition related to flying.

Nice is used in phrases like "nice and easy", "nice and cool". It's a general term something like "good".

... Yes. 'Nice and low' connotes 'low enough for things not to turn nasty'. // 'on your approach' uses a metaphorical usage of 'on', meaning 'during'/'throughout'. But the sense is better paraphrased as 'as you approach the target'.

Merriam-Webster has "nice and" at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nice%20and

The game is using aviation terminology. An "approach" is the phase of the flight where you are "approaching" something - usually an airport if you are a normal plane,  a target if you are military.
So "stay low on your approach" means to stay low when you are approaching the place you want to get to. Radars work less well when the target is near the ground, so this makes sense.
